# How to insert function to Directory/Hashtable

Tags: java, c#

I have this dictiory in c# and I need to rewrite it in Java.

```
    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, Func<object, byte[]>> FromTypeDict = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, byte[]>> {
        { typeof(byte), input => new byte[] { (byte)input } },
        { typeof(float), input => new byte[] { (byte)(((float)input) * 10) } },
        { typeof(ushort), input => IntToByte((ushort)input, 2) },
        { typeof(uint), input => Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => (byte)((((uint)input) >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF)).ToArray() },
        { typeof(string), input => (input as string)?.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray() },
        { typeof(PatientSetting), input => new byte[] { (byte)(PatientSetting)input } },
        { typeof(MacAddressCollection), input => {
            var coll = input as MacAddressCollection;
            return new byte[] { (byte)coll.Count }.Concat(coll.SelectMany(i => (byte[])i)).ToArray();
        } }
    };
```

I create a hash table

```
public static Hashtable<Type, Function<Object, Byte>> my_dict = new Hashtable<Type, Function<Object, Byte>>();
```

but I have no idea how to insert the same functionality in it.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less the translation you are requesting

```
public class FunctionHashtable {
    public static Hashtable<Class<?>, Function<Object, Byte>> my_dict = new Hashtable<>();

    static {
        // Duplicate below line as many times as needed
        my_dict.put(Float.class, (object) -> Byte.valueOf(object.toString())); // Replace Float.class with the class (type in c#), replace the lambada with you custom logic

    }
}
```

But I'm not sure why you expose the specific implementation of your map, and if a single Byte will work in you use cases, so this is a modified version exposing just a Map and using an array of bytes.

```
public class FunctionMap {
    public static Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, byte[]>> myDict = new Hashtable<>();
    static {
        // Duplicate below line as many times as needed
        myDict.put(Float.class, (object) -> object.toString().getBytes()); // Replace Float.class with the class (type in c#), replace the lambada with you custom logic

    }
}
```